# error while using if statement inside image in php

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, if-statement

i have a codeigniter php website, in the image tag I have given an if statement to determine the source, the code is like below:

```html
<img class="st_img" <?php if(str_replace(' ', '',$val['unique_tblkey'])=='entertainment'){?> src=" <?php echo ADMIN_IMG.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '',$val['unique_tblkey'])).'s/'.$val['image'][0]['btp_image'];?>"<?php} else { ?> src=" <?php echo ADMIN_IMG.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '',$val['unique_tblkey'])).'/'.$val['image'][0]['btp_image'];?> " <?php } ?>/>
```

I am getting

> unexpected '}'

this error is coming although there isn't any unwanted brackets, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code, thanks in advance

Comment: what is `<?php } ?>` supposed to do?

Comment: That looks quite unreadable. Either check that condition and prepare your source variable before image tag, or place if within src.

Comment: @berend close the else

Comment: `<?php}` => `<?php }` should fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finished rewriting it. Not completely sure if it will work, because I cannot test it.

```
<?php 

$tableKey = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $val['unique_tblkey']));
$url = ADMIN_IMG . 
       $tableKey . 
       ($tableKey == 'entertainment' ? 's/' : '/') . 
       $val['image'][0]['btp_image'];
echo '<img class="st_img" src="'.$url.'" />';
```

There's no repetition, multiple lines, and no mixing of PHP and HTML. This all makes for more readable code.